# MongoDB Filter only IF ANY

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Mongo Playgound](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JZFCsXHXgnk)

Lets say I have these results:

A)

```
[
{_id: 1, Name: 'A', Price: 10, xx:0},
{_id: 2, Name: 'B', Price: 15, xx:0},
{_id: 3, Name: 'A', Price: 100, xx:1},
{_id: 4, Name: 'B', Price: 150, xx:1},
]
```

B)

```
[
{_id: 1, Name: 'A', Price: 10, xx:0},
{_id: 2, Name: 'B', Price: 15, xx:0},
]
```

I want to:

- If exists at least one x:1, return all x:1 only
- If there is none x:1, return all x:0

Should I do a MAP & FILTER on root docs? or some kind of MATCH with conditionals? or Redact?

Results desired Ex.:

A) Removed x:0 because exists x:1, so returned only x:1

```
[
{_id: 3, Name: 'A', xx:1},
{_id: 4, Name: 'B', xx:1},
]
```

B) Returned only x:0 as there are only x:0

```
[
{_id: 1, Name: 'A', xx:0},
{_id: 2, Name: 'B', xx:0},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Group the documents by the `xx` field and add the grouped docs to the `docs` array using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).
2. Sort the docs by the `_id` field in descending order.
3. Limit the result to 1.

If there are documents with both `xx: 0` and `xx: 1` values, only the `xx: 1` group would be returned since we're sorting in descending order and limiting the result to the first group. If there are no documents with `xx: 1` but documents with `xx: 0` exist, the first group would be `xx: 0` which gets returned.

You can then use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind) to return a document for each grouped document and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to lift the document to the root level.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$xx",
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1,
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1,
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$docs"
    },
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3MYzypT0u4T)

---

If there might be docs with an `xx` value other than 0 and 1, you should filter those out using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) before grouping the docs using [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      xx: {
        $in: [
          0,
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$xx",
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1,
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1,
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$docs"
    },
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WfLx7h3oE5L)